# Lucene - MemoryIndex throwing exception on load

Tags: java, lucene

I am starting to use lucene. I use lucene 8.1.1
On create class MemoryIndex , the program throws exception.

I add library references :
lucene-memory-8.1.1
lucene-core-8.1.1

```
import org.apache.lucene.index.memory.MemoryIndex;

public class RunTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MemoryIndex mi = new MemoryIndex();
    }

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/index/memory/MemoryIndex
    at RunTest.main(RunTest.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.index.memory.MemoryIndex
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: What IDE, build tool are you using?

Comment: Hello, I use eclipse.

Comment: What about build tool? Maven, Gradle?